# Plugin tabs forwarding from first tab to second

Tags: jquery, html, css

I don't know how to forward to the second tab by click some href in first. Is it possible to do it?

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HSCwC/1/)

**Code**

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
<li><a href="#fragment-1"><span>One</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#fragment-2"><span>Two</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#fragment-3"><span>Three</span></a></li>
</ul>
<div id="fragment-1">
<p href="#fragment-2">active 2 tab</p>

</div>
<div id="fragment-2">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod 
tincidunt    ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod
tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
</div>
<div id="fragment-3">
3333333333333333333333333333<br>
3333333333333333333333333333<br>
3333333333333333333333333333<br>
3333333333333333333333333333<br>
</div>
</div>

<script>
$( "#tabs" ).tabs();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind a click event to the `p`:

```
// count from 0
$("#tabs").tabs("select", 1);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HSCwC/3/